# Who is Kenshin based on?

Tags: rurouni-kenshin

I've been told that Kenshin, at least partially, is based on a real life assassin. Who was he based on, and what pieces of his story are inspired by this person?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[According to the author](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himura_Kenshin#Creation_and_conception)<sup>1</sup>, he is based on [Kawakami Gensai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kawakami_Gensai), a Japanese samurai of the late Edo period, who was executed by the Meiji Government.

Not having seen the series nor being familiarized with the Gensai's story, I cannot tell you how much of it is based on samurai's story and how much of it is fiction.

---

<sup>1: *Watsuki, Nobuhiro (2003). "The Secret Life of Characters (1) Himura Kenshin". *Rurouni Kenshin, Volume 1*. Viz Media. p. 56. ISBN 1-59116-220-3.</sup>